# Use SQL to Delete Comma and Everything After in a String

Tags: sql

Using this statement:

```
UPDATE "FAFWD"
SET "PLAYER, TEAM POS" = LEFT('PLAYER, TEAM POS', CHARINDEX(';', 'PLAYER, TEAM POS') - 1)
```

I keep getting this error:

> Access is denied: CHARINDEX in statement [UPDATE "FAFWD" SET "PLAYER,
>   TEAM POS" = LEFT('PLAYER, TEAM POS', CHARINDEX(]

Comment: Wow...that, um, seems like something you should have mentioned up front

Comment: Do I need a more advanced DBMS?

Comment: Actually, that's not even a DBMS...

Comment: I am now using Microsoft Access and still no dice.